# create server with node and get endpoint with React Native

Tags: node.js, json, react-native

I have json file and created node.js server to set endpoint and then get this data via my React Native application. If I'm not wrong it worked correctly in friday but I had to mess something up and now I totally don't know how to fix it. All time I get error:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: Network
>   request failed
>   self.fetch/http://192.168.1.39:8081/1c49a23b-7fbb-c640-a946-c1e001192c92:27859:18
>   dispatchEvent@blob:http://192.168.1.39:8081/1c49a23b-7fbb-c640-a946-c1e001192c92:29144:13
>   setReadyState@blob:http://192.168.1.39:8081/1c49a23b-7fbb-c640-a946-c1e001192c92:28897:15
>   __didCompleteResponse@blob:http://192.168.1.39:8081/1c49a23b-7fbb-c640-a946-c1e001192c92:28724:11
>   send/<@blob:http://192.168.1.39:8081/1c49a23b-7fbb-c640-a946-c1e001192c92:28834:18
>   emit@blob:http://192.168.1.39:8081/1c49a23b-7fbb-c640-a946-c1e001192c92:4538:15
>   __callFunction@blob:http://192.168.1.39:8081/1c49a23b-7fbb-c640-a946-c1e001192c92:2608:22
>   callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue/<@blob:http://192.168.1.39:8081/1c49a23b-7fbb-c640-a946-c1e001192c92:2385:11
>   __guard@blob:http://192.168.1.39:8081/1c49a23b-7fbb-c640-a946-c1e001192c92:2561:13
>   callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@blob:http://192.168.1.39:8081/1c49a23b-7fbb-c640-a946-c1e001192c92:2384:9
>   onmessage@http://192.168.1.39:8081/debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.js:72:25

my Node server:

```
const filename = './logos.json';

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

        if (req.url === "/logo") {
            res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
            fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/logos.json").pipe(res)
        }
})
server.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('server is listening on port 3000');
})
```

and my RN code :

```
syncLogoData = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/logo')
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

Comment: your request is to port `3000` but error log shows `8081` `http://192.168.1.39:8081` double check again

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar 8081 is where React Native packager runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to run this on a device. The device doesn't know `localhost` points to your server. In your `syncLogoData`, change the uri to `http://ip_address:3000/logo` and it should work.

Also helpful to open `http://localhost:3000/logo` on your computer browser to make sure your server code is correct.

Comment: Thanks dude, I already solved this issue but in exactly same way as you just said So I'm gonna mark it as a correct answer:)